# Работа с кассовым апаратом

Tags: c#, внешние-устройства

Требуется написать программу для работы с кассовыми аппаратами (хотя бы печать чека). Подскажите в какую сторону копать. Есть ли программные эмуляторы кассовых аппаратов для отладки такого рода программ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для каждого торгового оборудования у разных производителей свои драйвера. Самые распространенные регистраторы - Штрих-М. Идем на [сайт](http://www.shtrih-m.ru/downloads), находим свой регистратор, качаем драйвера. Есть еще [АТОЛ](http://www.atol.ru/support/programs/), тоже популярны довольно. Доступ к драйверу идет через COM, в комплекте с драйверами есть примеры для 1C, delphi и билдера.

По поводу эмуляторов, то скорее всего нет. В любом случае проверять надо на реальном аппарате, т.к. в самом регистраторе существуют настройки - кассиры, отделы, виды оплаты, строки для печати в начале и в конце чека... Обычно тестируют на нефискализованном аппарате (стоимость штрихов, например, от 14к рублей), затем фискализуют его просто.

**UPD** Пару лет назад сделал класс для Delphi для работы с разными ККМ. [uKKMClass.pas](https://github.com/ivanovsuper/KKMClass). Там же реализация для регистратора Феликс-РК. Печать чека, снятие отчетов и т.д.

Comment: А можно обновить ссылку на uKKMClass.pas, а то она уже 404. Заранее большое спасибо.

Comment: @vanyamelikov, поправил.

Comment: @YuraIvanov в соседнем "ответе" просьба обновить ссылку ещё раз.

Comment: @D-side спасибо, выложил на гитхаб.